# How to use "mod" in XSLT

Tags: 2013, xslt

I am displaying two records from a list on home page.
Only the first record needs to show image while second record will not show image. Here's what they will display:

**First record**
Image
Title
Date

**Second record**
Title
Date

As you can see image needs to show only for first record. Right now it displays image for both records which I don't want. I want to use "mod" function to check if first record is coming then show image else not.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

See [XSLT special condition for first row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840585/xslt-special-condition-for-first-row)

You can do it by specifying a special template for the first element like this:

```
<xsl:template match="row[1]">
  ... html with image
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="row">
  ... html without image
</xsl:template>
```

or by using an if inside a foreach

```
<xsl:template match="rows">
  <xsl:for-each select="row">
  ... html for common start
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
  ... html for image
    </xsl:if>
  ... html for common end
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Tried the second solution you have given and it is not working in itemstyle.xsl. When I printed the value of position (to check why the condition is not working)  it printed "1" for both records.

Answer (score 1):

Also using position() would work too, like so:

```
<xsl:if test="position() = '1'">
 <img src="#" alt="heyo" />
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: I tried this but it is not working in itemstyle.xsl which is used in CQWP. I mean it doesn't display any error but it shows images for both records.